# Grams to cup measurements

Tags: measurements

Keeping question quite simple, I don't know much about measurings, so how many cups make 218 grams, and also when u say for example a cup what should be the size of that cup?

Comment: 218 grams of what, exactly? Flour? Sugar? Rice? Venezuelan Beaver Cheese?

Comment: 218 grams of flour

Comment: 1 cup of salt weighs 288 grams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow this table as a reference when converting grams to cups or vice-versa
https://www.allrecipes.com/article/cup-to-gram-conversions/

See this link for more information about cups and its standards https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cup_(unit)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 9):

**Grams of *what*?**

Grams is a measure of weight (actually mass, but we'll assume you are cooking on earth).

Cup is a measure of volume.

Different substances have different density, and powdered items like flour can be more or less packed or settled.

To confuse things a bit, in the USA we have ounces (weight) and fluid ounces (volume). When we talk about volume in fluid ounces, a shorthand is to just say ounces.

One cup = 8 (fluid) ounces.

But that 8 fluid ounces can be:

*approximately* 4.5 ounces of flour, really 120-130 grams, depends on the grind and the sift

*approximately* 8 ounces of water (that is where fluid ounces came from)

a bit more than 8 ounces butter

etc.