# How many of this mug would be 750 grams of flour

Tags: dough, flour, measurements, weights

To make pizza dough, I'm trying to measure 750 grams of flour. However, I don't have access to any weight measurement tool or any standard cup. I have this mug as unit of measurement. I wonder how many of this mug would roughly be 750 grams of flour?

[image: mug]

Cup diameter is 7 cm

[image]

Cup height is 8 cm

[image]

Comment: There's no possible way to give you an answer to this, you need to give a volume measurement of the cup.

Comment: Two issues: the walls of the cup aren't straight, and the 7cm measurement is taken between the outer edges of the cup. I think the inner diameter is about 6.4cm, which (treating the cup as a cylinder) gives a volume of about 250mL (no point in being more precise).

Do you have no containers of which you *know* the volume? Or do you perhaps know the *total* mass of the flour you have?

Comment: If you want good results you need some decent measuring equipment, which isn't hard to find. Invest in a measuring cup and a scale, guesswork will lead to inconsistent results.

Comment: @LSchoon and 250ml would _probably_ be close enough to count as 1 cup, considering the variance introduced by the different flour measuring methods.

Comment: Even if, or once, you figure out the volume of your mug, see this almost duplicate for a discussion of converting volume of flour to mass or vise versa. I am going to ask to close the question as a duplicate because this specific question will be of little use to future searchers. Almost dups: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/107612/grams-to-cup-measurements/107614#107614 https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2915/standard-weight-conversions-for-converting-cups-of-flour-to-grams-of-flour?noredirect=1&lq=1 and others

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Standard weight conversions for converting cups of flour to grams of flour?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2915/standard-weight-conversions-for-converting-cups-of-flour-to-grams-of-flour)

Answer (score 7):

Buy a 500g pack of flour. Fill the cup with flour and measure how many cups can fill 500g of flour. You can then do simple math to understand the weight of flour each cup is holding.

Comment: also: for 750g of flour just use 1 1/2 packets, doesn't even need the cup!

Comment: Or if flour is sold in 1kg packs (like where I live), do the exercise with that.

Comment: @Stephie: First divide the pack into two, then divide one of the halves into two, then take one half and one half of half and you've got yourself 750g. Alternatively, divide the 1kg pack to 1000 equal parts, then take 750 of them.

Answer (score -1):

[Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+cup+of+white+flour) it is mentioned that :

```
serving density | 0.58 g/cm^3 (grams per cubic centimeter)
```

Therefore, based on the reported dimensions, the flour weight would be:

```
pi / 4 * 7 * 7 * 8 * 0.58 = 178.568 grams
```

For a more precise answer, the cup dimensions should be measured with more precision.

---

Thanks to @Damila  and [this post](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/2919/80108).

Comment: This answer only addresses *one* of the problems of your previous answer (why didn't you just edit that one, by the way?), namely the conversion of volume to mass. The 'serving density' as WolframAlpha calls it can vary wildly depending on how tightly you pack your cup. It also still has the inaccurate calculation of the cup's volume. The advice to invest in a scale is still the best response.

Comment: @LSchoon Right ☺️ I'm going to buy a scale.

Answer (score -4):

On [this website](https://www.kingarthurflour.com/learn/ingredient-weight-chart) it is mentioned:

[image]

Therefore, 4.25 ounces of flour might weight 120 grams. Also it is known that 4.25 ounces is 0.0001256875 cubic meters:

[image]

My cup volume is:

```
pi / 4 * 7 * 7 * 8 * 10^-6 = 0.00030787608 cubic meters
```

Therefore reach cup would weigh around:

```
0.00030787608 / 0.0001256875 * 120 = 293.944342914 grams
```

Please let me know if my calculations are missing something!

Comment: Buy a scale. Seriously, they cost very little and you will be able to bake with precision.

Comment: Agree with @GdD...this will only get you an estimate.  You also have to recognize that humidity is a factor, as is the compacting of the flour.  Also, with a scale, you use one bowl, and don't need spoons and cups.  It is a far superior method.

Comment: You are overestimating your cup volume by around 20%. As I said in a previous comment on the question: the walls of the cup are not perfectly straight (the cup is smaller at the bottom) and the 7cm you measured include the walls of the cup, which seem about 3mm wide. Other than that, as other people have said, get a scale.

Comment: There is another problem: the 4.25 ounces given by King Arthur is the *mass* of 1 cup of flour, **not the volume**. 1 cup = 8 fl. oz = about 236 mL. Thus, even if your calculation for the volume of the cup is roughly OK, your final mass is off by almost a factor 2!

Comment: In short, fluid ounces ≠ ounces, unless we are measuring  water. For everything else, this will cause a more or less significant error. Flour has (very roughly) half the density of water -> factor 2. Find more [here](https://www.thekitchn.com/whats-the-difference-between-ounces-and-fluid-ounces-224303).

Comment: And all that isn’t considering the difference between the “scoop-and-level” vs. the “spoon-and-level” methods, sieved, stirred or compact flour straight from the pack. There is a reason a good recipe will _at least_ specify the method and we keep touting the benefits of a basic kitchen scale.

Comment: This answer needs to be changed. It takes one problem and compounds. it with totally incorrect information.  Even setting side all the problems with variation between weights of flour of the same volume, even this answer confuses fluid ounces (ounces used as a volume measurement)  and ounces (weight, mass really). 1 cup = 8 fluid ounces. In flour, that weighs about 4.25 ounces.